# React - How to detect when image resources are fetched when implementing skeleton screen?

Tags: reactjs, lazy-loading

I've been trying to follow some online tutorials for how to implement skeleton screen placeholders for content that will take a bit to load in or content that we want to lazily load.

I'll see something like this:

```
const App = () => {
  const [videos, setVideos] = useState([]);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    setLoading(true);
    const timer = setTimeout(() => {
      setVideos(dummyData);
      setLoading(false);
    }, 5000);
    return () => clearTimeout(timer);
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="App">
        { loading && <Skeleton />}
        { !loading && <NormalComponentHere /> }
    </div>
}
```

But as you can see we have this arbitrary loading timer that toggles the `loading` property. However, in my case, how do we actually know when a resource (or a series of resources) have been fetched and ready for rendering?

Let's say my code is like this:

```
const MyPage = () => {
    return (
        <div>
            <img loading="lazy" src="https://some-slow-url.com/image1.png" />
            <img loading="lazy" src="https://some-slow-url.com/image2.png" />
            <img loading="lazy" src="https://some-slow-url.com/image3.png" />
        </div>
    )
}
```

How do I know when the browser has finished fetcheing to `image1.png`, `image2.png`, and `image3.png`? Surely, I shouldn't just set an arbitrary `setTimeout` and hopefully there's a way to do so without a whole bunch of JavaScript Promises for every image (or maybe that's the only way?)

Edit: Would be nice to know how to do this for `img` tags and `source` tags. I tried using the `onLoad` property (purposefully placed before the `src` attribute like so):

```
<img loading="lazy"
     onLoad={() => console.log("I am done loading image")}
     src="https://some-slow-url.com/image.png" />
```

But nothing renders in my console.

Comment: Maybe you want the onLoad property?

Comment: @LindaPaiste Hm..okay that seems to be what I want. However, `onLoad` does not appear to be fired at all.

Comment: Is is not fired because the image never loads?  Or the image loads but it never gets called?  It *should* get called so I don't know what's going on.

Comment: Using Chrome developer tools to throttle the network speed, the image eventually loads but the onLoad never fires. Regardless, I'd need to do something like `{ loading && <img onLoad={() => setLoading(false)} /> }` which wouldn't make sense since the `loading` flag is already hiding the `<img>`